# 'With-in' duplicate GPRBuild name files

Tags: gnat, gprbuild

I try to build a_project (3rd party) where:

```
a_project.gpr
--> with config.gpr
--> with a_lib.gpr

a_lib.gpr
--> with config.gpr
```

note 1: config.gpr in a_lib and a_project are distinct files. 
note 2: both config.gpr are 'abstract project'.

The building process tells me:

```
config.gpr:15:18: duplicate project name "config"
config.gpr:15:18: already in "...\a_lib\config.gpr"
```

What should be done to make this work?

Thx.

Comment: using `config.gpr` for 2 projects in the chain is a bad idea. Rename one of them. gprbuild has no way of knowing which is which (note that in the projects you just reference `config'Source_Dirs` or such so it uses project name, not path.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "note that in the projects you just reference config'Source_Dirs or such so it uses project name, not path" I dont get this one?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre 1- It looks like it's working for the author of those projects. 2- Would it not be great if gprbuild could distinguish per project 'naming'? It 'feels ok' that each project provide a config.gpr file definition... doesn't it?

Comment: each project, yes, but you cannot mix them. Maybe the original author used an older version of gprbuild where it didn't check this particular point.

Comment: it should be too difficult to rename one of the config files, inside it (project config => project config2) and the with statements. Then it's done :)